# How do I prevent PostgresQL users/roles from having access to any administrator functions?

Tags: postgresql, security, postgresql-11

When I create a user with `CREATE ROLE user123 LOGIN` on my system it is able to login and immediately perform `\du` and interact with pg_stat_activity, and probably many other things.

I have programmatically connecting software that should be performing a specific task. I don't want it to be able to do anything else, including spying on the connections, userIDs, user permissions or other things.

How do I prevent all unspecified access?